# Flutter: How to capture images on macos?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-desktop

I want to show a `camera` preview and capture images on a desktop application. The official flutter `camera` and `image_picker` packages **do not support** any desktop and I can't find another package to do this. suggest something Especially for the **macOS** desktop app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've developed a package that can help you with this.

It hasn't got all the functionalities of the main plugin, but it's just temporary until an official implementation from the Flutter team comes along.

Here's the link: https://pub.dev/packages/camera_macos

Answer (score 1):

The only solution at this time seems to be by building a plugin for camera for macOS.

You can read more on building plugins in the official documentation:

- [Developing packages & plugins](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages).
- [Writing custom platform-specific code](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-swift-tab)
- [Binding to native macOS code using dart:ffi](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/macos/c-interop)

For the Swift code required you would need to access Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For desktop, you can use the [file_selector](https://pub.dev/packages/file_selector) plugin.

```
dependencies:
  file_selector: ^0.9.2+1
```

Comment: this is just for picking files I want to capture images and also show a camera preview.